# Opportunity Product Quick Action Aura component with recordEditForm and inputField on lookup not displaying input fields when creating a record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

Problem overview:

- I want to create a new record using a Quick Action (on Opportunity Layout for a new Opportunity Product) using lightning:recordEditForm.
- The component recordEditForm has lightning:inputFields for lookup fields Opportunity and Product.
- It also has lightning:inputFields for Quantity and UnitPrice.
- My client's org is Professional Edition (which means no Apex code!)

**UPDATE:**  <strike>I found one error in my component.  The OpportunityId will not be set correctly by using {!v.recordId} - that's going to be the Id of the OpportunityLineItem record (and it doesn't exist yet ...).</strike>   *It is getting set correctly from the Opportunity.*

The thing is: When I click on the Opportunity Quick Action, NONE of the input fields show up in the panel.  The recordEditForm is completely empty - I verified this by dumping the form values using an event handler for onsubmit.

Component markup:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId" 
access="global">

    <!--  Lightning action on the opportunity object. Clicking the Component's action button on the Oppty layout opens a panel to create a new Oppty Line Item.  -->

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleLoad}" /> 

    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                           objectApiName="OpportunityLineItem" 
                           onsubmit="{!c.handleLoad}" >
        <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:inputfield aura:id="opportunityProductField" fieldname="OpportunityId" value="{!v.recordId}" 
                              disabled="false" required="true"/>
        <lightning:inputfield aura:id="opportunityProductField" fieldname="Product2Id" disabled="false" required="true"  />
        <lightning:inputfield aura:id="opportunityProductField" fieldname="Quantity" />

        <lightning:inputfield aura:id="opportunityProductField" fieldname="UnitPrice" />

        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Submit" />

    </lightning:recordEditForm>

</aura:component>
```

Client controller:

```
({
    handleLoad: function (cmp, event, helper) {

        var obj = cmp.find("recordEditForm");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
})
```

The Quick Action LX Component when it renders:

[image: The Quick Action LX Component]

---

Of course, the record is not going to save if the fields are empty, and here is the message when I click 'Submit':

"An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.

Required fields are missing: [OpportunityId, Quantity]"

Any assistance would be appreciated.  Some of the of SFSE posts mentioned that record creation doesn't work well in LX component lightning:RecordEditForm.

Another post indicated that the inputFields must be populated with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code looks fine but **fieldname** in below line should be **fieldName** and it will work fine.

Wrong:-

```
<lightning:inputfield aura:id="opportunityProductField" fieldname="OpportunityId" value="{!v.recordId}" disabled="false" required="true"/>
```

correct:-

```
<lightning:inputfield aura:id="opportunityProductField" fieldName="OpportunityId" value="{!v.recordId}" disabled="false" required="true"/>
```

you need to change in every input field.

Comment: @[sanket kumar] Thank you, sir!  It's component markup (not Javascript), but the same rule applies.  I'm now able to move forward and break the component some other way.

Comment: @TalkinData yes